# Javascript getter - why does it get called at construction?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ecmascript-5

I'm new to Javascript getters/setters, but thought to use them in my Leaflet- and browserify-based project. Got a surprise.

The getter gets called at initialization, for some reason unknown to me, before the class's own `initialize` method (Leaflet construction callback) gets to run. This of course means members are undefined and all breaks up. Why is this?

- is this general behaviour with JavaScript getters?
- is this induced by Leaflet (maybe a bug in it)?

Unfortunately, I haven't got a jsfiddle to showcase this - it may be due to Leaflet, or due to node.js like modular build (via browserify) that I do.

Here's the code:

```
/*
 * Temp.js
 */
"use strict";

module.exports = L.Class.extend( {

  initialize: function () {
    console.log("initialized");
  },

  // --- Public methods ---

  get some () {
    console.log("getter");
    return 42;
  },

  set some (v) {
    console.log("setter: "+v);
  }

});
```

Calling code:

```
// this just for experiments
//
var Temp = require('./src/Temp.js');
var xxx = new Temp();
```

Produces the output:

```
[Log] getter (out.js, line 2102)
[Log] initialized (out.js, line 2096)
```

So: what might call the `get`?

Using: Safari 8.0.6 (OS X), Leaflet current `master`, Browserify 10.1.0

*Addendum*:

Debugging, the line that calls the getter is [this one](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/core/Util.js#L20) in Leaflet.

Comment: Fairly important to know whether the first line is logged during the `var Temp = require('./src/Temp.js');` or during the `var xxx = new Temp();`.

Comment: Separately: Are you sure `L.Class.extend` is compatible with getter/setter properties? The usual `extend` implementation in various toolkits isn't. So that's where I'd be looking.

Comment: *"Debugging, the line that calls the getter is this one in Leaflet."* I really don't think it is, I think something's gotten confused there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The first line is logged during the require call. Thanks for the answer, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Leaflet, but the *usual* implementation of `extend` has a loop that looks something like this:

```
var propertyName;
for (propertyName in source) {
    dest[propertyName] = source[propertyName];
}
```

As you can see, that *reads* the value of the property at the point you're calling `extends` (and stores the resulting value, instead of the getter function).

You'll want to check the docs, but I doubt `L.Class.extend` is compatible with getters/setters. You may need to define those getters/setters in `initialize` instead, e.g.:

```
var somePropDef = {
  get: function() {
    console.log("some getter");
    return 42;
  },
  set: function(v) {
    console.log("some setter: "+v);
  }
};
module.exports = L.Class.extend( {

  initialize: function () {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "some", somePropDef);
    console.log("initialized");
  },
});
```

Comment: I also did a PR towards Leaflet that would make it compatible for ECMAscript5 getters/setters in application classes. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3464

Comment: @akauppi: Cool, fantastic of you to contribute back. That particular pull request probably won't be successful. The problem is that `__lookupGetter__`/`__lookupGetter__` and `__defineGetter__`/`__defineSetter__` are not valid ECMAScript (and never will be). They're Mozilla-specific JavaScript. You're looking for [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.3) and [`Object.defineProperty`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6)).